# put_connections() to Facebook graph in Koala fails after a very long delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using Rails 3.2.5 and Koala 1.3.0 (not the latest, because the latest refuses to run even the sample Facebook app from Heroku). Web server is Unicorn.

When I try to POST to timeline using put_connections():

```
@fbgraph   = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:access_token])
logger.debug "put_connections(#{url_for @room}), start"
@fbgraph.put_connections("me", "myapp:view", :room => url_for(@room))
logger.debug "put_connections(), end"
```

The controller stalls for 12s before getting an exception:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12075ms

Koala::Facebook::APIError (HTTP 500: Response body: {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Could not retrieve data from URL.","code":1660002}}):
```

I tested with the debug tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
and it found no error for the URL logged in line 2.

My web server logs a GET from Facebook IP and returns 200 OK. Facebook IP then makes some more requests to fetch images, which also gets 200 OK.

I am testing this on my app's test users FYI.

**UPDATE**

This seems to be an OpenGraph issue. This problem reproduces for me: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/213733412077729

Basically the POST is successful only after I test it on the debugger once! Anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out. Of course the debugger thing doesn't make sense. It worked because Facebook then has my view on their cache.

This is a classic reentrancy problem (which I can't believe I have to deal with in Rails!) -- Facebook's POST API is synchronous and it only returns after it calls back to my show controller. But since I only have 1 worker thread, there is no one servicing the request, thus the hang.

The fix is to invoke the API asynchronously in a thread.

```
Thread.new {
    @fbgraph.put_connections("me", "myapp:view", :room => url_for(@room))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the clue I needed to fix my problem too.   I think the root cause is that doing synchronous external service calls in your controller is 'bad'.  The 'technically more correct' architecture is to have your action submit some sort of background job (delayed job, resque, etc) and not block your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem as you, but with a get request that manage more than 600 calls to FB (with total time > 16s).

Explicitly declare the fields seems that works.

```
graph = @FBGraph.get_object("#{user.fb_user_id}?fields=id,name,username,picture,link")
```

For more info see my Q/A in stackoverflow [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729802/rails-koala-error-unsupported-get-request-after-long-task-fail/13733541#13733541)