# Rails koala "error unsupported get request" after long task - calling FB graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-opengraph, koala, koala-gem

After a long task (14s and can be more with more than 600 call to Facebook) my app returns a 500 internal server error with the following description:

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError (GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request.)
```

What I do is something like this:

```
@FBGraph = Koala::Facebook::API.new
tud = MyUsers.all
tud.each do |user|

    graph = @FBGraph.get_object(user.fb_user_id)
    picture = @FBGraph.get_picture(user.fb_user_id)
    thisTud = MyUsers.find(user.id)
    thisTud.name = graph["name"]
    thisTud.url = graph["link"]
    thisTud.url_pic = picture

    if thisTud.save
        puts "Saved!"
    else
        puts "Error"
    end
end
```

I receive (on the terminal) all the `"Saved!"`, but after retrieving the data, it does automatically the mysql operations and it fails. And the data is not saved on the DB.

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007616/put-connections-to-facebook-graph-in-koala-fails-after-a-very-long-delay) I have placed the `@FBGraph = Koala::Facebook::API.new` in a new Thread, but nothing changes.

*Note:* when I'd do the same operations with less users, all was working good.

Comment: there's a bug http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/160155304123891. Less users just lower the probability to have that error i guess.

Comment: thanks, you have right. Meanwhile I have find a workaround solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How hellvinz says is a facebook bug.

I have find a workaround for now that seems that works:

change this

```
graph = @FBGraph.get_object(user.fb_user_id)
```

to this

```
graph = @FBGraph.get_object("#{user.fb_user_id}?fields=id,name,username,picture,link")
```

Explicitly declaring the fields seems that solve the problem.

And if this is not sufficient there are 2 more tricks that can resolve the problem:

1. Calling again after a time delay (for example after an hour), and calling only the requests incomplete
2. Creating multiple fb app ID and accounts differentiating the requests with the accounts

Comment: This is a facebook bug. If you had done more calls than the API allowed you would have a different error message.